# How to use multiple player prefabs for Unity's new UNET?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

Has anyone got multiple player prefabs working (eg different character classes with different prefabs) on the new Unity UNET Networking?

Answer (score 5):

Finally got it working!
Massive thank you to @ClausKleber for their answer at 
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-set-individual-playerprefab-form-client-in-the-networkmanger.348337/#post-2256378

Edited working version below, Works with the Network Manager HUD to create and join.

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NetManagerCustom : NetworkManager
{
    // in the Network Manager component, you must put your player prefabs 
    // in the Spawn Info -> Registered Spawnable Prefabs section 
    public short playerPrefabIndex;


    public override void OnStartServer()
    {
        NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(MsgTypes.PlayerPrefab, OnResponsePrefab);
        base.OnStartServer();
    }

    public override void OnClientConnect(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        client.RegisterHandler(MsgTypes.PlayerPrefab, OnRequestPrefab);
        base.OnClientConnect(conn);
    }

    private void OnRequestPrefab(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {
        MsgTypes.PlayerPrefabMsg msg = new MsgTypes.PlayerPrefabMsg();
        msg.controllerID = netMsg.ReadMessage<MsgTypes.PlayerPrefabMsg>().controllerID;
        msg.prefabIndex = playerPrefabIndex;
        client.Send(MsgTypes.PlayerPrefab, msg);
    }

    private void OnResponsePrefab(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {
        MsgTypes.PlayerPrefabMsg msg = netMsg.ReadMessage<MsgTypes.PlayerPrefabMsg>();  
        playerPrefab = spawnPrefabs[msg.prefabIndex];
        base.OnServerAddPlayer(netMsg.conn, msg.controllerID);
        Debug.Log(playerPrefab.name + " spawned!");
    }

    public override void OnServerAddPlayer(NetworkConnection conn, short playerControllerId)
    {
        MsgTypes.PlayerPrefabMsg msg = new MsgTypes.PlayerPrefabMsg();
        msg.controllerID = playerControllerId;
        NetworkServer.SendToClient(conn.connectionId, MsgTypes.PlayerPrefab, msg);
    }

    // I have put a toggle UI on gameObjects called PC1 and PC2 to select two different character types.
    // on toggle, this function is called, which updates the playerPrefabIndex
    // The index will be the number from the registered spawnable prefabs that 
    // you want for your player
    public void UpdatePC ()
    {
        if (GameObject.Find("PC1").GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn)
        {
            playerPrefabIndex = 3;
        }
        else if (GameObject.Find("PC2").GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn)
        {
            playerPrefabIndex= 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MsgTypes is undefined

Comment: MsgTypes is not defined and where did you call updatePC

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class that derives from the built-in NetworkManager script. In there, just add a few supporting fields and an override for OnServerAddPlayer().

```
[SerializeField] Vector3 playerSpawnPos;
[SerializeField] GameObject character1;
[SerializeField] GameObject character2;
// etc.

GameObject chosenCharacter; // character1, character2, etc.

// Instantiate whichever character the player chose and was assigned to chosenCharacter
public override void OnServerAddPlayer(NetworkConnection conn, short playerControllerId) {

    var player = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(chosenCharacter, playerSpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
    NetworkServer.AddPlayer(conn, player, playerControllerId);

}
```

Reference: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetManager.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I updated the code to use a chosenCharacter, which you could set when the player is choosing a character, however you're doing that. Does that help?

Comment: Did u try this code ? I think chosenCharacter is same with host everytime.